# Pyspark 'column' object is not callable, when performing sum()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe t.

This dataframe has a datecolumn 'testdate'. I want to clip the dates in this columnn, as well count how many times this happens

```
b = t['testdate'] < F.lit('2017-02-01')
counts = b.sum()
t.withColumn('testclipped', when(b, '2017-02-01').otherwise(F.col('testdate'))
```

the third line of codes runs, however, b.sum() raises the error:
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

It is not clear to me why exactly this raises error, or how I can workaround this error

Comment: what do you want to do ? what is `b.sum()` (or `(t['testdate'] < F.lit('2017-02-01')).sum()`) supposed to mean for you ?

Comment: I want to count how often it happens that I have to clip the date in 'testdate' column because it is out of the clipping boundaries

Comment: then probably do `counts = df.where(b).count()`

Comment: Okay thanks. Because I am working with very large datasets, I wanted b to be only evaluated once. However, I am aware that spark performs lazy evaluations. Is the above code indeed the fastest way to perform counts as well clip the data?

Answer (score 0):

```py
b = t['testdate'] < F.lit('2017-02-01')
```

returns `Column` object and you can't use `sum` on it.

use `where` to get the `DataFrame` back and then you can use `count` or `groupBy` and `sum`.

Example:

```py
counts = t.where(t["testdate"] < F.lit("2017-02-01")).count()
```